# jQuery toggle() function. I would like some critique or suggestions for better practice

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, toggle

My code is working as I would like it to, but I am looking for any critique on how it could be trimmed or modified to be more efficient:

```
$('.toggle-comments').hide(); // this hides the results div when the page loads.                   
$(".comments-toggle-click").click(function () {                             
  $(".toggle-comments").slideToggle("slow");
  $(".comments-toggle-click").remove();
});
```

Comment: Hide the comments via CSS, not jquery. I find CSS hiding much faster than waiting for the DOM to load, then hiding them.

Comment: Rather than `$(".comments-toggle-click").remove()` you could write `$(this).remove()`. This approach is preferable unless you're actually removing multiple elements.

Comment: It's good practice to hide in jquery, rather than CSS. Otherwise non-js users/screenreaders, whatever else still get to view the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling `$('.toggle-comments').hide();` on page load why not render the comments with `display:none;`?

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
.toggle-comments {
  display: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.comments-toggle-click').click(function () {                             
  $('.toggle-comments').slideToggle('slow', function () {
    $('.comments-toggle-click').remove()
  })
})
```

The trick is to pass [`.slideToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) a callback function if you want to delay the removal of the link until the animation is complete. This may or may not be the problem you elude to in your question.